# Can't get a sum by Description

Tags: mysql, sorting

```
DECLARE @CurrentWk DATE = CAST(DATEADD(day,(-1*DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()))+2,GETDATE()) AS DATE 
SELECT  
sum (JobOpDtl.EstProdHours) as [ProdHours],  
JobOper.DueDate,  
JobOpDtl.ResourceGrpID,  
Resource.[Description] as [ResDes],  
CASE 
  WHEN CAST(DATEADD(day,(-1*DATEPART(DW,JobOper.DueDate))+2,JobOper.DueDate) AS DATE) < @CurrentWk THEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, @CurrentWk)
  ELSE CAST(DATEADD(day,(-1*DATEPART(DW,JobOper.DueDate))+2,JobOper.DueDate) AS DATE) 
END AS [DueWk]
FROM Erp.JobOpDtl

 JOIN Erp.JobOper ON  
JobOper.JobNum = JobOpDtl.JobNum  
AND JobOper.OprSeq = JobOpDtl.OprSeq

JOIN Erp.JobHead ON  
JobHead.JobNum = JobOper.JobNum

JOIN Erp.Resource ON  
Resource.ResourceGrpID = JobOpDtl.ResourceGrpID  
AND Resource.ResourceID = JobOpDtl.ResourceID

WHERE JobHead.JobClosed = '0'  
AND JobOper.OpComplete = '0'  
AND JobOper.AssemblySeq = '0'  
and JobOper.JobNum NOT LIKE '%-w%'

GROUP BY  
Resource.Description,  
JobOpDtl.ResourceGrpID,  
JobOper.DueDate
```

This is pulling the results but I am trying to sum by the week and by ResDes. Example
5.00,   2018-10-04, NCFP-T, 3-AXIS ROUTER - TULSA,  2018-10-01
0.50,   2018-10-05, NCFP-T, 3-AXIS ROUTER - TULSA,  2018-10-01

Should be
5.50,   2018-10-04, NCFP-T, 3-AXIS ROUTER - TULSA,  2018-10-01

I am at a loss. Thank you all for help.

Comment: The due dates are different in the two records and you are grouping by on the due date, so you get the expected output. You have to describe the logic how to group differently by the due date, so that 4 and 5 October is grouped together. Or perhaps you should remove the due date from the query and just include `DueWk` and group by on the due week.

Comment: Its great you have showed what you have so far, but it will be better to give us some initial background as well.

Comment: I use the due date to calculate the due week. That is what I want to sum up. If I remove the due date from the group by, it tells me I have to have that in there because I use it as a field to get the due week.  I am trying to create a capacity chart.